Is it intended that .meta:n strips a pair of braces?
If a value is passed to a key defined with the l3keys .meta:n handler, it seems to strip one pair of braces in the process. This question is just to confirm that this is the intended behavior and, if possible, an explanation for "why" (I know such questions are often difficult to answer).
I noticed this because if the value contains a comma, then it works fine if contained in braces for the original key mykey but fails if the same argument is passed to a meta key mykey2 defined as mykey2 .meta:n = { mykey=#1 }. Here is an example.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    mykey  .tl_set:N = \l_mymodule_tl,
    mykey2 .meta:n = { mykey=#1 },
    mykey3 .meta:n = { mykey={#1} },
  }
\keys_set:nn { mymodule } { mykey={abc,def} } % works
\keys_set:nn { mymodule } { mykey2={abc,def} } % errors
\keys_set:nn { mymodule } { mykey3={abc,def} } % works
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}

The error is
! LaTeX Error: The key 'mymodule/def' is unknown and is being ignored.

So I assume the braces around the value for mykey2 are stripped and the keyval parser is interpreting the argument as mykey2=abc,def. My expectation was that defining mykey2 .meta:n = { mykey=#1 } means "pass #1 to mykey as-is", i.e. without any brace stripping. But there may be a good reason for this behavior, hence my question.

@cfr It's not obvious to me that that's how .meta:n should behave. Also, the unbraced mykey2=value does work as long as #1 does not contain a comma, whereas the unbraced equivalent in your example \def\mycmd value does not work. So the keyval parser is regarding the whole thing as a single token, at least up to commas

@cfr I do see your point about comma-delimited arguments to \def though. It's not clear to me though why one wouldn't want the argument of a .meta:n key to retain the number of braces, especially since it's just a shortcut for setting other keys

all I meant was that stripping the outer braces is the standard way tex works. but I'll delete it.

@cfr No need to delete (unless I missed something)

Yes: this is entirely the normal behaviour. Whenever you give a <key> = <value>, l3keys will remove exactly one set of braces if they completely surround the <value>. So if you are passing on arbitrary user input which may itself contain , or = tokens, you need to add exactly one set.

This answer serves to give a bit of rationale in addition to @JosephWright's answer.
In order to support arbitrary user input (that means values containing =, or , or are surrounded by {}) a key=value system needs to have very predictable behaviour regarding these tokens.
While there are different approaches to = around (some implementations like l3keys throw an error if there is more than one = outside of any braces, others just consider the first to be the separator between key and value and any additional ones as part of the value, and others ignore any second = and everything following it -- that last approach is by far the worst, imho, as it isn't as predictable), the handling of , is pretty universally agreed upon: Any , outside of braces denotes the end of the current key=val-list element (rather obviously and there is no other possibility other than simply using another delimiter, which then faces the same behaviour).
This leaves us with the problem of how to input something like a,b as a value. We need to put it inside braces so to hide it from the splitting on ,. So we end up with input key={a,b}. But we wanted that without braces, hence the implementation must strip one set of braces to allow for that input. And if we then want to input {a,b} as value we need to use key={{a,b}}. So long as an implementation always strips exactly one set of outer braces (if they are found) we can indeed have arbitrary input in a predictable manner.
And for that reason, every step of key absorption strips exactly one set of braces (in correct key=value implementations -- this is not the case for every key=value package available in LaTeX), and that's a fact absolutely independent on the used key-handler/key-type (as the stripping happens on a way lower level). So in your usage for every one of your keys #1 will be abc,def, and a .meta:n handler means that whatever the result of replacing #1 with the value in the predefined list given (mykey=#1 or mykey={#1} in your examples) happens to be will be considered as additional key=value input. Hence your mykey2={abc,def} is equivalent to mykey=abc,def and your mykey3={abc,def} is equivalent to mykey={abc,def}.
